# Spring Security OAuth: [invalid_user_info_response]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I inherited an app that uses OAuth login via Spring Boot & Spring Security, and when I try to login with valid credentials, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService.loadUser(OidcUserService.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService.loadUser(OidcUserService.java:66)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
...
```

The exception is thrown by [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e57e8b3722e796724a4b5ebcce16b165c869fcdf/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.java#L127), specifically when the following condition is met:

```java
if (!userInfo.getSubject().equals(userRequest.getIdToken().getSubject()))
```

When debugging, I noticed that `userInfo.getSubject()` is returning "CORPO\MyUsername", where "MyUsername" is the user name I used to login, and `userRequest.getIdToken().getSubject()` is returning an 8 digit number, such as "12345678", which are not equal and hence the exception is thrown.

But I have also noticed that `userInfo` has a claim with name `ssouid` whose value is the exact same 8 digit number ("12345678" in our example).

Is this perhaps some configuration issue, or incompatibility of the OAuth server with my app?

My app uses Spring Boot 2.7.9 with spring-security-oauth2-client 5.7.7

**EDIT:** I've found out that the currently deployed version uses Spring Boot 2.4.4 and it works, so the error must've been caused by upgrading to 2.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** As a hotfix, downgrading `spring-security-oauth2-client` to version `5.7.5` helped, but that's not a definitive solution.

**Explanation:**

I was debugging to see difference between the old working version of `spring-security-oauth2-client` (`5.4.4`) and the new version(`5.7.7`).

The difference was, that method [OidcUserService.shouldRetrieveUserInfo(...)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/abc523c063becc72de115cae9a6fa29d374ab549/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.java#L157) in the old version returned `false`, which meant that the code which throws the exception didn't get executed.

The [new version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/faadadf71a10f2523d57230ff664ecf52aafd251/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.java#L157) of the method returns `true` because of [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/faadadf71a10f2523d57230ff664ecf52aafd251/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.java#L181), which checks if the access token scopes are empty. The check was added in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/fde26e003a648a670be40c690a028970f0d1137b), which is a part of version `5.7.6`. That's why downgrading to version `5.7.5` solved my issue.

Also worth of noting is the fact that in the older version, the scopes were not empty like in the newer version. This is because of [another commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/75004587a419a96d18909030b20c6b16b226ecbe), which changed the implementation of `DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient`. This commit was a part of version `5.7.4`.

So my problem was caused by the combination of the two aforementioned commits. I'm still not sure whether this is a bug in Spring Security, or a configuration issue with the OAuth2 server which I'm connecting to.